# Polly "retry" throws TaskCanceledException on first failure retry attempt

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retrypolicy, delegatinghandler

I have implemented Polly in it's own "retry" HttpClient `DelegateHandler` in a dll written to .NET Standard 2.0.  I have the Polly v7.2.3 package. My `HttpClient` is running separate from an `HttpClientFactory` since only one instance will ever exist during the short lifetime of the dll.

My problem is this: The code executes great when my internet is working.  However, when I disconnect my internet it throws a `TaskCanceledException` on the first retry and does not retry any more.  Here are the relevant parts of my code...

inside the ctor of my typed HttpClient:

```
this.Client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(
new ATCacheDelegatingHandler(
    new RetryPolicyDelegatingHandler(
        new HttpClientHandler()))));
```

inside my Retry delegating handler:

```
this.RetryPolicy =
Policy.Handle<HttpRequestException>()
    .Or<TaskCanceledException>()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(numRetries,
        retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt-1) * 15));
```

So I did my research here on SO and found this very promising explanation and solution that suggested I call `Dispose` on the result.  [HttpClient Polly WaitAndRetry policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62806212/httpclient-polly-waitandretry-policy)

Here is my updated code using that solution.  The call to `WaitAndRetryAsync` complains it is unable to resolve the `OnRetry` method because it is looking for an 'Action<Exception, TimeSpan>'

```
private void WaitAndRetry(int numRetries)
{
    this.RetryPolicy =
        Policy.Handle<HttpRequestException>()
            .Or<TaskCanceledException>()
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(numRetries,
                retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt-1) * 15)
                , OnRetry); // reference to the method below
}

// unable to match to these parameters from the "WaitAndRetryAsync" call above
private Task OnRetry(DelegateResult<HttpResponseMessage> response, TimeSpan span, int retryCount, Context context)
{
    if (response == null)
        return Task.CompletedTask;

    // this is the "Dispose" call from that SO solution I referenced above
    response.Result?.Dispose();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Unfortunately there is NO support for a `DelegateResult<HttpResponseMessage>` parameter in the version of Polly I am using.  All `onRetry` support expects the first parameter to be an "Exception".  I am dead in the water using the `Dispose` solution if I can't access the disposable object.

**Update:** I want to be able to call `Dispose()` to affect the fix from the other StackOverflow feedback. But I can't because the `onRetry` method does not support the same set of parameters (i.e., the "response" object). It looks like the Polly API has changed. If so, what is the new way to gain access to the response so I can `Dispose` of it? Either that or is there another way to resolve the error I am getting?

So I am stuck trying to get this solution working or finding another way to resolve this exception.  I welcome any feedback on how to specify the object to Dispose.  Alternative approaches are also welcome.

Comment: What is your question? How to solve the compilation error?

Comment: There is indeed a `WaitAndRetryAsync` overload which accepts your `OnRetry` method: [Polly's source code](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/c27faf89ef459fd9a8e0131ae1d4cd835ca4f31d/src/Polly/Retry/AsyncRetryTResultSyntax.cs#L471)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I want to be able to call "Dispose()" to affect the fix from the other StackOverflow feedback.  But I can't because the OnRetry method does not support the same set of parameters (i.e., the "response" object).  It looks like the Polly API has changed.  If so, what is the new way to gain access to the response so I can Dispose of it?  Either that or is there another way to resolve the error I am getting?

Comment: No, it did not change. If you look at the source code and enable blaming then you can see that overload has not been updated in the last 6 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to specify the `HttpResponseMessage` as a return type when you declare your policy.

```
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> retryPolicy = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
    .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
    .Or<TaskCanceledException>()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(numRetries,
    retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt - 1) * 15), 
        OnRetry);
```

So, instead of `Policy.Handle...` use `Policy<HttpResponseMessage>.Handle...`

Comment: @JeffLehner I've copy-pasted your code from the question into .NET 5 console app and fixed the compilation issue. Did you change the type of the this.RetryPolicy as well? In your case it was IAsyncPolicy.

Comment: I did something similar here and the build problem went away.  I need to wait 30 minutes before I can test it.  Thanks for sticking with me.  I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: That fixed my "build" problem!  Thanks for your help!  Also, now I am seeing the retries.  Thank you for your help!